# Has every totally real number field got a “sign” basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a totally real number field of degree $n$ with real embeddings $\sigma_i$ for $i=1,...,n$. Let “sign” be the sign homomorphism $F^*\rightarrow \{\pm 1\}^n$ defined as $sign(x):=(sgn \, \sigma_i(x))$. Is it true that I can always find $n$ elements in $F^*$, say $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$, such that their images, under the “sign” map, are generators for the multiplicative abelian group $\{\pm 1\}^n$? More in general, the “sign” is always surjective?

Answer (score 4):

The sign is always surjective. Indeed, the real embeddings corresponds to the real places of you number field, or if you prefer, to the real absolute values.

If $\sigma$ is an embedding, recall that $\vert x\vert_\sigma=\vert \sigma(x)\vert$.

Since you have only finitely many real places, by the strong approximation theorem, you can always find an $x$ of given sign:

for an embedding $\sigma_i$, let $a_i\in\{\pm 1\}$. By strong approximation, you can find $x$ such that $\vert x-a_i\vert_{\sigma_i}=\vert \sigma_i(x)-a_i\vert\leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $i$, i.e. $a_i-\frac{1}{2}\leq \sigma_i(x)\leq a_i+\frac{1}{2}$ for all $i$ . In particular, $\sigma_i(x)$ will have the sign of $a_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It’s so clear! How did I not think about it?! Have a good day

Comment: @FedericoRomagnani If you think the answer is clear and satisfying, dont' forget to accept it, so that the question is marked as closed.